# Hard coding dropdown list on the view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have a string input type and I want it to remain string. But I want the user to chose from a list of options when he inputs the information. So I want to add a drop down list but I don't know how to do it. I don't want to create any model or any list in the back end ... I want to be able to do this on the view only.

Here is my initial code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you want to "hard code" it, why don't you just add your HTML [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) into the code?

Comment: I tried but I am having problem binding it with the model :/

Comment: You won't be able to bind it to the model if it's not defined in the model.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what would be in the drop down list ?

Comment: cubrr I did it your way and I got what I need it .. You can suggest it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use any viewmodels/Html helper methods for rendering your dropdown, you may simply use pure Html. Just keep names for your form elements and use that as parameters of your HttpPost action method.

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  <input type="text" name="userName"/>
  <select name="state">
    <option value="MI">Michigan<option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio<option>
  </select>
}
```

And your HttpPost action would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register (string userName,string state)
{
  //check the parameter values now
  // to do : Save and redirect.
}
```

If you are already having a ViewModel object as parameter for your HttpPost action method, You can add the SELECT element name as second param and it will still work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register (CreateUserVM model,string state)
{
  //check the parameter values now
  // to do : Save and redirect.
}
```

I am not quite sure about your exact use case, **If you have more than 1 or 2 form elements you are posting, I recommend using a view model and rely on MVC Model binding.** Adding the dropdown data to the viewmodel is not that hard.

```
public class CreateUserVM
{
  public string UserName {set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> EmployeeTypes {set;get;}
  public int SelectedType {set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action method, Load the EmployeeTypes collection and send it to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm= new CreateUserVM();
  vm.EmployeeTypes = GetEmployeeTypes();
  return View(vm);
}
public List<SelectListItem> GetEmployeeTypes()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "1",
            Text = "PERM"
        },
        new SelectListItem
        {
                Value = "2",
                Text = "Temporary"
            }
    };
}
```

And in your view,

```
@model CreateUserVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(v=>v.UserName)
  @Html.DropdownListFor(s=>sSelectedType,Model.EmployeeTypes,"Select one")
}
```

And in your HttpPost action, Read the SelectedType property to get the selected Item's value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register (CreateUserVM model)
{
  //check the model.SelectedType
  // to do : Save and redirect.
}
```

If you do not want to hard code the Employee Types in the server side code, Create a db table and store it there and read it in your GET action method. This will allow you to add a new employee type to the system without touching the code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Here is some basic code to create a dropdownlist in a view:

```
@{    
    var listitems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "One", Value="1"});
    listitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Two", Value="2"});
}

@Html.DropDownList("DropDownListValue", listitems)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to fill the data in the View, but you want to use:

```
@Html.DropDownList
```

So your code would be something along the lines of....

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeType, "Employee Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeType", new SelectList(new List<string> { ... }, "EmployeeType", "SelectListName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obviously you need to actually put your strings into that list some how. Personally I would create or get the list in the controller and pass it in a ViewBag.  Then you could just...

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeType", new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeeTypes, "EmployeeType", "SelectListName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Looking at your comments, this would also bind the option chosen to EmployeeType.